# SQL Server not using all CPU cores/threads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008-r2

After upgrading our SQL Server's hardware, we noticed in the Windows Task Manager that the SQL instance is only using half of the "threads" available to it (see screenshot)[image: Task Manager].

The server has the following hardware and software:

- Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64bit SP1
- Intel Xeon E7-4870 - 4 processors (40 cores, 80 threads)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

Running `select cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info` returns 40.

The OS sees all 80 threads. [SQL Server Standard Edition supports 4 Physical CPUs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143760.aspx) which is what we have here.

Why is only half the server's processing power being used?

We have the same hardware and software on two servers and they both exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Wow.What sort of database is using this type of hardware

Comment: Dumb question, but are you using a non-standard affinity mask?

Comment: no my affinity mask set with "Automatically set processor affinity mask for all processors" but i thing i must buy sqlserver License per core , now i am using sql server 2012 Enterprise Edition , Is it true ?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2012 is licensed by cores and for intel CPUs 1 core license is equivalent to 1/4 of an old style CPU license, I have a few servers with 2 or 4 8 core CPUs and the enterprise licensing costs for those is shockingly high :-(

Comment: SQL 2012 EE Server+CAL model has a 20 physical cores limitation.  To access all 40 cores you need to move to core based licensing.